# error: cannot access zzeuq class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq not found please

Tags: java, android-studio

I am facing this error in my project here is my gradle build...

Despite my research I could not solve...

I'm waiting for your help...

https://i.hizliresim.com/7B34rY.png

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'

implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.3'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+')
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.TheBrownArrow:PermissionManager:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.github.demoNo:AutoScrollViewPager:v1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.sujithkanna:smileyrating:1.6.8'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.tubb.smrv:swipemenu-recyclerview:5.4.4'
implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.norbsoft.typefacehelper:library:0.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.yinglan.shadowimageview:shadowimageview:1.0.4'
implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
```

I solved the solution after hours of research.

The reason for the error versions of implementation 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-maps: 11.6.0' and implementation 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-location: 11.6.0' I solved it by replacing it with 16.0.0.

Comment: It would help others if you would post the answer and accept it.

Comment: If you have found an answer for your problem, it'd be better if you [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing your original question.